# How to get user input from javascript object to controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to bind value of date-picker(javascript) to model in post method?

Here is my simplified view:

```
@model myProject.Models.Order

@using (Html.BeginForm("NewOrder", "Projects", FormMethod.Post, new { @class 
= "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()


        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker-inline" charset="UTF-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootsrap")
}
```

I feel like I need to do sth like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserMessage, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

but it's date, not text and it's somewhere in this div tag. 
How to get it right?

Comment: *"Please walk me through.."* is not a proper question. Stackoverflow is not a *"how to"* tutorial site. Please take some time to read [ask]

Comment: you need to have input hidden or textbox and it's name should be what you have in model as property on which you want to map the value when form posted

Comment: Without a `name` on a form control nothing will submit for that control

Comment: Ok, if I got you right: 1) put invisible textbox for user with model property 2) give name to javascript control the same as to this textbox. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your model looks something like this

```
public class Order 
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime OrderDate {get;set;}
}
```

in your view write

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderDate);
```

`[DataType(DataType.Date)]` will generate type="date" in the Html.TextBoxFor call

Then on document ready tie all your date types to the datepicker.  Use whatever options you need

```
jQuery(document)
    .ready(function() {
    jQuery("input[type=date]")
        .datepicker({ dateFormat: "m.d.yy", changeYear: true, yearRange: "-4:+0" })
        .attr("type", "text");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but where to put this jQuery function? I have 2000 lines of javascript code imported to Scripts folder... Should i modify this plugin or rather stick it in view?

Comment: Do you have a external js file for your site or page?  where are you putting js you write now?  I would put it there.  worst case you could put it in a <script> tag on the page or layout.

Comment: thanks - javascript sits in external file in Scripts folder. I use script rendering as you can see in my last lines of my question. Thanks to those responces I made it work. How to mark this question solved?

Comment: Click the check mark on the left side of the answer.